# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split' Discord Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So i was developing my discord bot for my discord server, and i came up with the idea to make an Redeem Code System so my members can have an redeem code and get an access on private channels.

In this time i want to generate first a redeem code for example: **Discord-24s265256dhbwd**
then after i created this i proceed on creating an duration or time for the subscription valid date for example: **Your plan is valid till: 345 day(s) 12 hour(s) 34 minute(s)**

But i am having a trouble in **SPLIT.()**
I am having this AttributeError
**`File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 880, in _do_call raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'createkey' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has  no attribute 'split'`**

And this is the code:

```
@tree.command(name = 'createkey', description='Redeem a code.')
async def createkey(interaction: discord.Interaction, duration: int):
    #Parsing the duration string into a minute.
    durationParts = duration.split(" ")
    durationString = 0
    for part in durationParts:
        if part[-1] == 'day(s)':
            duration += int(part[:-1]) * 24 * 60
        elif part[-1] == 'hour(s)':
            duration += int(part[:-1]) * 60
        elif part[-1] == 'minute(s)':
            duration += int(part[:-1])
```

Whats wrong with my code?

I tried to find solutions but i cant find a solutions that can fix it.

Comment: You declared the parameter as `duration: int` (and not just declared that way, you also tried passing an int in the runtime). But it should be "duration string"

Comment: Your duration  parameter is declared as type int, which doesnt have method split(). I also there is a problem with your code, the durationParts will be something like `['Your', 'plan', 'is', 'valid', 'till:', '345', 'day(s)', '12', 'hour(s)', '34', 'minute(s)']` so the part[-1] with be the last character of each part. And you assign `+=` the result to duration variable directly, that will give a wrong result. If you want extract all datetime value from the string with a fixed format, you may try regex.

Comment: Why are you trying to split an integer, anyway?  What is the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you call `split()` on a `int` variable `duration`, which doesn't have method `split`. You may want to change its type to `str`

Second, I see what you want to do with these codes and your code won't work because of the `durationParts` will be something like this after `split()`: `['Your', 'plan', 'is', 'valid', 'till:', '345', 'day(s)', '12', 'hour(s)', '34', 'minute(s)']`, and `part[:-1]` will be the *the original list except the last element*, I think you meant `[-1]` but in this case it will return the *last character of string*

To extract and calculate the duration from the string with this format **Your plan is valid till: 345 day(s) 12 hour(s) 34 minute(s)**, I suggest using regex.
For eg:

```
import re
durationString = "Your plan is valid till: 345 day(s) 12 hour(s) 34 minute(s)"
@tree.command(name = 'createkey', description='Redeem a code.')
async def createkey(interaction: discord.Interaction, durationString: str):
    durationParts = re.findall(r'\d+', durationString) //findall match the format \d+
    // \d: match digit
    // +: one or as many as possible times
    // ['345', '12', '34']
    duration = int(durationParts[0]) * 24 * 60 + int(durationParts[1]) * 60 + int(durationParts[2])
    // 497554
```

**Note**: I assumed the string is fixed as that format, always contains days, hours, minutes, eg: *0 days(s) 1 hours(s) 10 minutes(s)*

---

Or to extract exactly as the way you already go with, you can split the string by `"(s)"` instead of `" "`

```
durationString = "Your plan is valid till: 345 day(s) 12 hour(s) 34 minute(s)"
durationParts = durationString.split("(s)")
// ['Your plan is valid till: 345 day', ' 12 hour', ' 34 minute', '']
```

From here I will check for the last word of each element in the array if they match `day`, `hour` or `minute` and extract the number in front of them.

```
duration = 0
for part in durationParts:
    words = part.split(" ")
    if len(words) > 1:
        if words[-1] == "day":
            duration += int(words[-2]) * 24 * 60
        elif words[-1] == "hour":
            duration += int(words[-2]) * 60
        elif words[-1] == "minute":
            duration += int(words[-2])
// 497520
```

I hope it helps!